# Error while calling Matrices Multiplication Function in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I created this function to do a simple matrix multiplication

```
 int[] MatrixMul(string[] input, int[,] key)
        {
            int[] result = new int[input.Length];
            for (int row = 0; row < key.GetLength(0); row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < key.GetLength(0); col++)
                {
                   result[row]+= key[row, col] * AtoZ.IndexOf(input[0][col]);

                }

            }
            return result;
        }
```

However, when I'm trying to call it, it's giving me some errors:

Calling the function:

total=MatrixMul(outPut[i],key);

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'Hill_Cipher_CSharp.Hill_Cipher.MatrixMul(string[], int[*,*])' has some invalid arguments  c:\users\wael\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Hill_Cipher_CSharp\Hill_Cipher.cs   34  23  Hill_Cipher_CSharp

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'string[]'  c:\users\wael\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Hill_Cipher_CSharp\Hill_Cipher.cs   34  33  Hill_Cipher_CSharp

The problem is with "outPut", and here is outPut:

```
IEnumerable<string> output = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length / key.GetLength(0))
    .Select(x => input.Substring(x * key.GetLength(0), key.GetLength(0)));
            string[] outPut = output.ToArray();
```

Comment: `output` and `outPut`? Enough to not even make me want to try. But at any rate, your error is because `outPut` is a type `string[]` and you're trying to pass in `outPut[i]` (a single string) to a method expecting a `string[]` (an array of strings). Pretty much exactly what Error 2 told you.

Comment: I got you, but I need to pass each string[i] alone,
i.e. outPut[1] = "TH";
I want to pass this string and then deal with each character inside the function as it's mentioned above. 
How would I be able to do so?

Comment: Check `for (int col = 0; col < key.GetLength(1); col++) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Function Should be like:

```
 int[] MatrixMul(string input, int[,] key)
        {
            int[] result = new int[input.Length];
            for (int row = 0; row < key.GetLength(0); row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < key.GetLength(0); col++)
                {
                   result[row]+= key[row, col] * AtoZ.IndexOf(input[col]);

                }

            }
            return result;
        }
```

calling function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < outPut.Length; i++)
            {
                encChars = MatrixMul(outPut[i], key);
            }
```